# Referring to ObjectIDs directly in MongoDB works, but not in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The first code snippet achieves the desired effect:

```
//in mongodb console:
db.collection.update({"username":"name"}, {$pull : { "task" : { "_id" : ObjectId("55280205702c316b6d79c89c")}}})
```

Yet this second (seemingly equivalent) code snippet written in Mongoose does not:

```
//in Mongoose:
var taskID = "55280205702c316b6d79c88c"
var pull = { $pull : {}};
var idObj = {};
idObj["_id"] = taskID;
pull.$pull["task"] = idObj;

collectionModel.update({"username": "name"}, pull) //fails to work since taskID just shows up as a literal string 55280205702c316b6d79c88c instead of ObjectId("55280205702c316b6d79c88c")
```

Other things I've tried:

- making `var taskID` equal to the string `'ObjectId(\"55280205702c316b6d79c88c\")'`
- setting `var taskID` equal to `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("55280205702c316b6d79c88c")`

How can I achieve the effect in the former code snippet in Mongoose?

Comment: You realize you have `{$pull: { $pull: {task: "876498127634987126398451}}}` right? did you intend to nest $pull twice?

Comment: You're right -- there was a typo in my example that's fixed now.  It still doesn't work even fixing for this typo.

Answer (score 1):

Import ObjectId type and use it in your query :

```
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId; 
idObj["_id"] = new ObjectId("55280205702c316b6d79c88c");
```

Comment: This doesn't work -- `new ObjectId("55280205702c316b6d79c88c")` just returns `"55280205702c316b6d79c88c"`.  It needs to return `ObjectId("55280205702c316b6d79c88c")` (which is distinct from the string `"ObjectId('55280205702c316b6d79c88c')"`, which also doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

After you did the **`$pull`** operation in mongodb shell and tried the same update operation in Mongoose with the same ObjectId, it didn't work because the task array object element with `"_id": ObjectId("55280205702c316b6d79c88c")` was removed by the previous mongodb shell operation.

Try first running the same query from Mongoose but with a different and existing taskID which is cast to ObjectId. You could add an extension to the String object as follows:

```
String.prototype.toObjectId = function() {
    var ObjectId = (require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId);
    return new ObjectId(this.toString());
};

var taskID = "55280205702c316b6d79c88d".toObjectId(); // a different _id
collectionModel.update( 
    { "username": "name" }, 
    { "$pull" : { "task": { "_id": taskID } } }, 
    function (err, result) {
        console.log(result);        
    }
);
```

Comment: It turns out it wasn't working because `update` in Mongoose doesn't actually execute a mongo command unless `.exec()` is tacked on at the end, or the "optional" callback is added to it.  Otherwise, it just returns a query that doesn't actually execute!